# Can't override Bootstrap variables in a Next.js project

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, next.js

I'm trying to override the primary color in Bootstrap but it just doesn't work. Btw I'm using NextJS.

This is my "globals.scss" which I have imported in "_app.js".

```
$primary: black;
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

And I have imported Bootstrap in index.js like this

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

I tried looking it up but everything I tried didn't work.
What I've tried:

- Importing functions, variables, and mixins from Bootstrap SCSS.
- Rearranging the imports.
- Importing bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss to "_app.js"

But I've noticed that in the inspector it says my primary color is black but then right above it changes back to the original:

Below:

[image: my color]

Above:

[image: original color]

Comment: The C in CSS stands for "cascade". Think about the order of yours.

Comment: Have you tried using `$primary: black !important;`?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't work either and I tried reordering the imports, and nothing.

Answer (score 3):

## How to override Bootstrap variables in a Next.js project

Let's create an app and try to change the `$primary` color from default to black.

#### App structure:

[image: App structure]

#### Code:

**`index.js`**

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name='description' content='Generated by create next app' />
        <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>
          Welcome to <a href='https://nextjs.org'>Next.js!</a>
        </h1>

        <button type='button' className='btn btn-primary mt-4'>Primary</button>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**`_app.js`**

```
import '../styles/globals.css'

import { useEffect } from 'react'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js');
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

**`globals.scss`**

```
$primary: black;

@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

#### Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work :/

Comment: I edited my answer. It's hard to say, but I think it has to do with your imports.

Comment: @Cervuscamelopardalis You put two lines of code and then a link to **bootstrap** docs in your answer. But that link says: ```Include any default variable overrides here```, here means before ```@import ```. Also other links you said in comments done before ```@import ```. Could you explain please why you say ```$primary: black;``` must be defined after ```@import```?

Comment: I edited my answer. @Jakooob **Remove `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'` from `index.js`.** If you add this line, you are adding Bootstrap twice to your project (in `globals.scss` and `index.js`). That's why you see `--bs-primary: black;` overridden by default Bootstrap color.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem of your codes is about the **order** of importing files. If you use `globals.scss` file to change bootstrap default values, Then you must import that file after your main bootstrap file. I'm not sure about the project structure you have, but for example if you **imported Bootstrap in index.js file**, change that file from just this:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

To something like this:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'your/path/to/globals.scss'
```

Maybe that overrides the bootstrap file with your custom file.